# Parametros en .NET MVC

Tags: html, c#, sql, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una aplicación .NET MVC , tengo las tablas "reportes" y "comentarios" , quiero que al seleccionar cierto reporte se pueda hacer un comentario (enviándole un dato identificador como parámetro , en este caso TITULO , para que pueda relacionar directamente el comentario con su reporte)

En el index HTML del Reporte tengo lo siguiente:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
       
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TITULO)
        </td>
      
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DETALLES)
        </td>
      
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID_REPORTE }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID_REPORTE }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID_REPORTE })
            @Html.ActionLink("Add comment", "Create","COMENTARIOs")
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Y en el index de crear comentario (actualmente lo tengo como una DropDownList):

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID_REPORTE, "ID_REPORTE", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })//
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ID_REPORTE", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_REPORTE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

La pregunta es cómo puedo enviar el valor del titulo hacia el otro html ?

Comment: Y... cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: No comprendo bien el problema, ¿Quieres que al hacer click en titulo te salga un input para escribir? ¿Quieres enviar el valor de título al pulsar en el ActionLink?

Comment: Perdón por no expresar la pregunta bien.  Exacto , la pregunta es esa , ¿Cómo puedo enviar el valor del titulo hacia el otro html ? Gracias